# How to detect if current process is suspended?

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, suspend

Hello I am making an launcher/anticheat for a game and yesterday I have discovered that users can simply suspend the anticheat thread with Process Explorer and inject hack and then clean up used dlls and then unsuspend it and hack. 
I have tried to find any way how to detect it but have found only how to suspend a process nothing about how to detect it I have also looked at Application and Process event but found nothing usable.. 
Now I have added a "timer" inside of the anticheat thread that will shut down the game if there is no process/module scan for 3 sec but when the game is loading it takes almost 100% cpu for some time and for my its about 2sec but on some older processors there are no scans for maybe up to 10sec so its not an option at all..

So is this event logged anywhere? or how can I do so? I know I can find process or thread state but not when all my threads are suspended

Comment: What do you mean? A suspended process or thread is just that: suspended. Your code isn't executing. How _could_ it "know" that it's been suspended? Absent a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're trying to do, your question is too broad at best. There are too many possible scenarios matching your description, and too many answers to go along with them. But really, you seem to have chosen a self-defeating route in your quest.

Comment: You could always try the RobinHood/FriarTuck gambit (see http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/meaning-of-hack.html) - have two processes monitoring each other for suspicious behaviour :-)

Comment: Peter my question should be is there any log of process state or can I raise event on process being UNsuspended for example? I was thinking about making two aplications checking each other too but I want to avoid that if its possible..

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any good option to do... but there are 3 possibilities that might work

1. **Create 2 processes**

   - First is main process that contains all code and
     will scan for second process
   - Second process will scan for Main
     process (like @paxdiablo says)

   How to bypass it? Select two processes at once and suspend them.

   Some users will try to select 2 processes at once.
2. **Search for opened processes and if Process Explorer is running then kill it**

   How to bypass? Use another task manager with suspending option

   Disadvantage? Your AntiCheat-Launcher can be detected by Anti-Virus.
3. **Embed your code in game code (eg. modifications).**

   I think that it's the best option... but if this game isn't written in C# (eg. Minecraft) then you must learn a new language.